# How to use init method in codable when you have model inside?

Tags: ios, swift4, codable, decodable, swift4.1

New in this code world and thanks in advance,

I am getting error

> Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'ModalA.ModalC?'

Here is my model class,

```
struct ModalA: Codable {
    struct ModalB: Codable {
        let value2: String?
        let value3: ModalC?
        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case value3 = "Any"
            case value2 = "Anything"
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            value2 = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .value2)
            value3 = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .value3) // getting error on this line
        }
    }
    struct ModalC: Codable {
        let value3: String?
    }
    let value1: ModalB?
}
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: As LowKostKustomz said, you don't want `String.self` as the value to decode. But, you don't need an `init(from:)` at all. `Codable` will do this for you.

Comment: hahaha , thanks for the correction Rob

Comment: @Rob with Codable I am getting error so thats why I added this init(from: ) ..

Comment: That error is something else, because it works fine without `init(from:)`, e.g.https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/3836defcc2aef31bc380f03431d563cc

Comment: U are champ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `value3` property is of type `ModalC`, but when decoding you are trying to parse `String` value (when passing `String.self` to `decodeIfPresent` method).

`decodeIfPresent` method takes type of decodable value as first argument. In your case `decodeIfPresent` method returns `String` value and you are trying to set `String` value to property of `ModalC` type.

So to solve the error you should say that you want to get value of type `ModalC` for key `.value3`. To do this you should pass `ModalC.self` like so:

```
value3 = try values.decodeIfPresent(ModalC.self, forKey: .value3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by

```
value3 = try values.decodeIfPresent(ModalC.self, forKey: .value3)
```

but declaring  value3 as optional

```
let value3: ModalC?
```

will fetch it if it's originally exists in the parsed json so `?` is enough

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
init(){

}


init(from decoder: Decoder) throws{

}
```

you can read my post [here](https://medium.com/@sajjadsarkoobi/how-to-write-strong-models-for-swift-codable-and-reusing-that-model-again-41a8779eef6f) for mor info.